Implementation of the lanczos algorithm to cross reference
I am trying to implement my own version of the lanczos algorithm. I would like to verify the output I am getting by checking against an easy to run and trustworthy implementation.
All I can find online returns the final eigendecomposition of a matrix rather than the tri-diagonal matrix. For example:
https://pypi.org/project/pylanczos/
https://github.com/mrcdr/lambda-lanczos
Neither of those seem to have a user facing documented cal to just give a matrix and obtain the tri-diagonalization.

scipy, matlab have implementations, though, you'll need to check to confirm, wolfram may also be a source , search online .... do some basic trawling/research
